# Android cannot connect to BlueZ server

Tags: java, android, c, android-bluetooth, bluez

I am using the following code. This is the code after device discovery works fine.

```
BluetoothDevice btdevice = adapter.getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress());
        btdevice.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
        ParcelUuid[] bt = btdevice.getUuids();
        for (ParcelUuid x:bt) {
            try {
                BluetoothSocket socket = btdevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(x.getUuid());
                socket.connect();
                if (socket.isConnected())
                    break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

On PC side I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and BlueZ version 5.48.
The server side code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>
#include <bluetooth/sdp.h>
#include <bluetooth/sdp_lib.h>

 sdp_session_t *register_service()
{

    uint32_t svc_uuid_int[] = { 0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000 };
    uint8_t rfcomm_channel = 11;
    const char *service_name = "Remote Host";
    const char *service_dsc = "What the remote should be connecting to.";
    const char *service_prov = "Your mother";

    uuid_t root_uuid, l2cap_uuid, rfcomm_uuid, svc_uuid;
    sdp_list_t *l2cap_list = 0, 
               *rfcomm_list = 0,
               *root_list = 0,
               *proto_list = 0, 
               *access_proto_list = 0;
    sdp_data_t *channel = 0, *psm = 0;

    sdp_record_t *record = sdp_record_alloc();

    // set the general service ID
    sdp_uuid128_create( &svc_uuid, &svc_uuid_int );
    sdp_set_service_id( record, svc_uuid );

    // make the service record publicly browsable
    sdp_uuid16_create(&root_uuid, PUBLIC_BROWSE_GROUP);
    root_list = sdp_list_append(0, &root_uuid);
    sdp_set_browse_groups( record, root_list );

    // set l2cap information
    sdp_uuid16_create(&l2cap_uuid, L2CAP_UUID);
    l2cap_list = sdp_list_append( 0, &l2cap_uuid );
    proto_list = sdp_list_append( 0, l2cap_list );

    // set rfcomm information
    sdp_uuid16_create(&rfcomm_uuid, RFCOMM_UUID);
    channel = sdp_data_alloc(SDP_UINT8, &rfcomm_channel);
    rfcomm_list = sdp_list_append( 0, &rfcomm_uuid );
    sdp_list_append( rfcomm_list, channel );
    sdp_list_append( proto_list, rfcomm_list );

    // attach protocol information to service record
    access_proto_list = sdp_list_append( 0, proto_list );
    sdp_set_access_protos( record, access_proto_list );

    // set the name, provider, and description
    sdp_set_info_attr(record, service_name, service_prov, service_dsc);

    int err = 0;
    sdp_session_t *session = 0;

    // connect to the local SDP server, register the service record, and 
    // disconnect
    session = sdp_connect( BDADDR_ANY, BDADDR_LOCAL, SDP_RETRY_IF_BUSY );
    err = sdp_record_register(session, record, 0);

    // cleanup
    //sdp_data_free( channel );
    sdp_list_free( l2cap_list, 0 );
    sdp_list_free( rfcomm_list, 0 );
    sdp_list_free( root_list, 0 );
    sdp_list_free( access_proto_list, 0 );

    return session;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    char str[1024] = { 0 };
    int s, client, bytes_read;
    sdp_session_t *session;
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);

    session = register_service();
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 11;
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));
    listen(s, 1);
    client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);
    ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
    fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if( bytes_read > 0 ) {
     printf("received [%s]\n", buf);
    }
    sprintf(str,"to Android.");
    printf("sent [%s]\n",str);
    write(client, str, sizeof(str));
    close(client);
    close(s);
    sdp_close( session );

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried with channels 1 and 11. I tried using the UUID I provided in C code and also the UUIDs by using `btdevice.getUuids();` and the Uuids that I am receiving are

- 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
- 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
- 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
- 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
- 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
- 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
- 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

The android code is able to pair to linux device but I think that't the system implementation of Ubuntu and not my code because it's not printing anything.
On android side it gives the following error on the line:

```
socket.connect();
```

> java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read
>   ret: -1

Please someone tell me what can I do? it has already taken one full day of my time.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question: Using sdp is not recommended with Bluez5. You can implement your profile as external profile and register with Bluez using `ProfileManager` interface. But libbluetooth should work still!

Comment: can you give refrences to your statement that sdp is not recommended with Bluez5 ?

Comment: As per porting guide here: http://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/ and based on https://youtu.be/tclS9arLFzk?t=1408